# locate user javascript return default address

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I need to locate my users with high precision using javascript.

At the moment I am using this lib https://github.com/onury/geolocator

With the folowing options

```js
var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 15000,
    maximumWait: 15000,     // max wait time for desired accuracy
    maximumAge: 0,          // disable cache
    desiredAccuracy: 30,    // meters
    fallbackToIP: false,    // fallback to IP if Geolocation fails or rejected
};
```

It's a little slow but most of the time working well.

But I have a geolocation issue from time to time, I do not really understand why but the output is:

```
{
    "latitude": 40.712742950000006,
    "longitude": -74.00595024412516,
    "formattedAddress": "New York City Hall, 260, Broadway, Civic Center, Manhattan Community Board 1, Manhattan, New York County, New York, 10000, United States of America",
    "country": "United States of America",
    "city": "Manhattan Community Board 1",
    "state": "New York",
    "zipcode": "10000",
    "streetName": "Broadway",
    "streetNumber": "260",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "neighbourhood": "",
    "provider": "openstreetmap",
}
```

Seems like a default position, but the script should use the browser location feature.

All users are executing the script from a mobile device

Comment: Just to be sure, did you check if the users did allow the browser to share their location with your website? Are they running from a browser or from an application?

Comment: We are doing it from a browser and id the user did not allow the request we have an error not a random address

Answer (score 3):

Set the timeout option to `Infinity` to avoid a return if position is not available (yet).

> HTML5 position timeout setting in milliseconds. Setting this to Infinity means that Geolocator won't return until the position is available.

See: https://onury.io/geolocator/?api=geolocator#geolocator.locate

Comment: Thanks but with `timeout: 'Infinity'` I have  an instant error `POSITION_UNAVAILABLE`

Answer (score 0):

this might be a low internet connection problem probably. Please try to disable or remove

```
maximumWait: 15000
```

now try it without that and also set the timeout option to `Infinity` as realAlexBarge said.